# Beagle bone - AP wlan1 needs to access eth0 as an IP Address

Tags: networking, network-interface, bridge, beagleboneblack

Using non-GUI Linux (beaglebone).

With the current setup

`Client (10.10.1.3 ... 254) <-> (wlan1 AP 10.10.1.1) bb`

I need to make clients (10.10.1.3 ... 254) have access the device (10.10.1.2).

`Client (10.10.1.3 ... 254) <-> (wlan1 AP 10.10.1.1) bb (eth0) <-> device (10.10.1.2)`

Here's the current `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    addess 192.168.2.28
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    network dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.225
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1


iface wlan1 inet static
    hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
    address 10.10.1.1
    network 10.10.1.0
    netmask 255.0.0.0
    broadcast 10.255.255.255
    wireless-power on
```

How to configure the file to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure the Beaglebone to either act as a *router* between wlan1 and eth0 (and optionally usb0 too), or to *bridge* the wlan1 and eth0 (and maybe usb0 too) interfaces.

Since your current configuration indicates your `eth0` interface has a different IP address segment from the one you're using on `wlan1`, routing would seem to be the appropriate option.

Here's a document for configuring a Beaglebone as a router:

https://pixelsvsbytes.com/2015/05/building-a-beaglebone-router/

If you need to use IP addresses from the same IP segment on both `wlan1` and `eth0`, then bridging would be the right choice instead. Unfortunately I could not find a Beaglebone-specific document, but this page on bridging in the Debian Wiki should be helpful:

https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

Comment: I think that the bridging is more appropriate, because I want the device itself to be configured with 10.10.1.2. In any case, how do I configure the /etc/network/interfaces? The previous time I tried bridging, I got locked out and had to flash bb to get it up again. Could you help by providing a /etc/network/interfaces ? Thanks.

Comment: That does not seem correct: if you bridge `wlan1` and `eth0`, then the interfaces will no longer have separate IP addresses: the address (or addresses, if you use IP aliases) should be assigned to the bridge instead. That would mean losing access to 192.168.1.* and 192.168.2.* networks, unless you do something else to keep that. Since your default gateway seems to be 192.168.2.1 (unless `usb0` is used), this seems kind of important.

Comment: Would adding `iface br0 inet static` `bridge_ports eth0 wlan1` `address 10.10.1.1` `broadcast 10.10.1.1` `netmask 255.0.0.0` `gateway 10.10.1.1`  and removing the settings for `eth0:1` and `wlan1` help?

Comment: Yes, but `wlan1` will still need at least the `hostapd` line, as that is specific to the actual wireless interface. So you'll also need at least `iface eth0 inet manual` for eth0 and `iface wlan1 inet manual` + the `hostapd` line for wlan1. But then the system will no longer be reachable as 192.168.2.28 nor 192.168.1.225 and won't be able to reach the gateway 192.168.2.1.